# Overriding editor template in theme affects admin view

Tags: orchardcms

I created a form using the CustomForms module and need to control the markup of the input fields I've included on the form (to add bootstrap specific classes). I added a view to my theme at the location `/Views/EditorTemplates/Fields/Input.Edit.cshtml` and that allowed me to update the markup for the input fields.

My problem is that the view in my theme is also being picked up in the admin views. I didn't expect this behavior but it's happening. I tried scoping the view override to the url (`Input.Edit-url-contact.cshtml`) and content type (`Input.Edit-ContactRequest.cshtml`) using the alternate naming conventions but they do not appear to work in this case.

Is there a way to scope the Input.Edit.cshtml view in my theme so it only applies to the front-end of the site? Or is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: That's clearly a bug. Would you mind filing it?

Comment: I created an issue for it: https://orchard.codeplex.com/workitem/20492

Comment: Any suggestions for working around the issue? Is it even possible to use alternates for these type of views?

Comment: Thanks for filing the bug. I don't see an easy way around it, except to implement a shape table provider to only create a specific alternate when not in the admin. Or put tests into the view and adapt the rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up working around this issue by implementing a shape table provider (based on Bertrand's suggestion) to specify different template names in my theme so they weren't picked up in the admin. Here's what it looks like:

```
public class EditorFieldShapeProvider : IShapeTableProvider
{
    public void Discover(ShapeTableBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Describe("EditorTemplate")
            .OnDisplaying(displaying =>
            {
                var shape = displaying.Shape;

                if (shape.ContentField is InputField) {
                    shape.TemplateName = "CustomInputField";
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Just drop that class somewhere in your theme and create your view at /ThemeName/Views/EditorTemplates/CustomInputField.cshtml